# Injecting variable before/during import

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.x

Basically, I'd like to force a variable, lets call him `jim` into a plugin I load as a global, *before* the plugin loads, for instance:

```
load_plugin('blah', variables={'jim':1}) #For instance
```

And then inside `blah.py`:

```
print jim #prints 1
```

Is there any easy way to do this? Not a big deal if its not in the standard library.

Comment: The duplicate actually has a correct answer. Never thought anyone else would try to do this :)

Comment: The accepted answer there won't work if the module does have a `jim = None` line. The `None` value would be override any value set in the two-phase loading, suggested in that answer. And if the line is not there, any attempt to use the `jim` variable in the module body would show up as an error for linter tools (it would still work in runtime as described, though)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use the [__import__](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__) function. It lets you override the globals.
for instance:

```
__import__('blah', dict(jim=1, **globals()))
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, although it really looks like it should. I still get `NameError: name 'jim' is not defined.`

Comment: The standard [`__import__] implementation [...] uses its globals only to determine the package context of the import statement. https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#__import__ - this answers, despite being accepted and upvoted is plain wrong.

Comment: I'm with @jsbueno, this is the accepted answer but it does not work.

Answer (score 2):

No - there is no way to do that *before* the plug-in is imported in first place - so, if your variable is used in the module body itself, you are out of luck.

If the variable is used as a global variable inside the module's functions or methods (but not class bodies), you can change it after the module is imported simply doing:

```
import module
module.jim = 5
```

as you probably know. (And I am aware this is not what you are asking for).

So, the only way to achieve that would be to parse the source code for the module, and change the variable assignment there, save the source code and import it. Ok, there are ways to emulate importing with the source code in memory, but this approach is so impratical, we should not detail it.

If you have control over the source of the module you want to monkey-patch this way, my suggestion would be to use a configuration file from which the module would pick the variable names.

Then you generate the configuration file, perform the importing (taking care that it is not already imported into sys.modules) and you are done.